# Fetch GET response handling

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

I am having some issues with Code by Zapier JavaScript trying to fetch some information from an API. I have success using the Webhook GET zap for the same API, but not using JS.

The reason for writing code is because I am trying to fetch and then immediately do some filtering on the response before sending it to the next step. I am now stuck, due to what I believe is a nuance in the response from the API.

```js
var url = '...';
var username = '...';
var password = '...';
var auth = new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');
var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': auth, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
};
fetch(url, options)
.then(function(res) {
    return res.json();
})
.then(function(json) {
    json = json.filter(value => value.Item1bID === '1434');
    callback(null, json);
})
.catch(callback);
```

Essentially, the Zapier error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token A` and `Object.parse (native) /var/task/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/body.js`

Here is a snippet of the response when doing a GET in Postman:

```
{
"odata.metadata": "...",
"nextLink": "...",
"value": [
    {
    "ForwardingAddress@odata.navigationLinkUrl": "...",
    "ForwardingAddress": [],
    "Item1aID": "0000010774",
    "Item1bID": "1434",
    ...},
 ...]
}
```

I have a suspicion that the error is due the capitalization of the JSON object string name found within the "value" array, but can't be sure.

Comment: Check the response in the network tab of the developer tools if it is valid JSON (https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link - the actual JSON response is valid